# Specific Semicolon vs. Dash Case

Tags: semicolons, dashes, em-dashes

and thanks for taking the time to read my question.

I was writing an essay not too long ago, and I ended up writing a sentence that goes like this:

> As people convert to higher-paid jobs the birth rate will lower and the numbers will remain small and sustainable - something which cannot be said about today’s society.

My peer suggested that the dash should go. I do see merit in using a semicolon in its stead, but I don't believe the dash to be wrong here. Is there one solution that the stack-exchange community prefers? Are either of the two wrong?

Comment: It looks fine. The dash marks the start of a (meta) comment about the earlier part of the sentence. It's a stronger *meta* marker than the semicolon, though interestingly the comma works as well.

Comment: I'd write *decrease* instead of *lower*. I like the hypen but it should be like–this.